# Generating valid random correlation matrices with non-negative entries

Tags: correlation, random-generation

The title is pretty self-explanatory.

I need to efficiently generate correlation matrices (i.e. semidefinite-positive, symmetric and all ones along the diagonal) of size $n$, with the limit that every coefficient should not be lower than 0.

All the algorithms I have found works with the classical boundaries of $[-1;1]$, but I need this boundary to be $[0;1]$. Do you know any way to do this?

Also, uniform distribution of the generated random matrices over the feasible domain of valid correlation matrices with the given constraints is a plus.

Comment: 1. Generate diagonally dominant matrix, but this seriously limits the population. 2 Generate a random symmetric matrix and push it through  semidefinite programming, but this can be slow

Comment: Generate a random wishart-ditributed matrix, as a start.